# lampp is not starting because "Another web server is already running"

Tags: lamp, xampp

I am new to Ubuntu, using 14.04. I have installed XAMPP but when I am trying to run it, I get an error about another web server already running.

[image]

Comment: Have you try to install apache httpd, mysql and php? Is there any reason to install XAMPP?

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have already installed and run apache httpd server. Better just remove XAMPP, install (if its not installed) mysql and php and voila, you have what you need